# Haskell Int64 inconsistent?

Tags: haskell, precision, biginteger

I am trying to solve the problem 2's complement [here](http://csfall11.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/solve/view/4e9639a73db8b/4e91289c38bfd) (sorry, it requires login, but anyone can login with FB/google account). The problem in short is to count the number of ones appearing in the 2's complement representation of all numbers in a given range [A, B] where A and B are within the 32-bit limits (2<sup>31</sup> in absolute value). I know my algorithm is correct (it's logarithmic in the bigger absolute value, since I already solved the problem in another language).

I am testing the code below on my machine and it's giving perfectly correct results. When it runs on the Amazon server, it gives a few wrong answers (obviously overflows) and also some stack overflows. This is not a bug in the logic here, because I test the same code on my machine on the same test inputs and get different results. For example, for the range [-1548535525, 662630637] I get 35782216444 on my machine, while according to the tests, my result is some negative overflow value.

The only problem I can think of, is that perhaps I am not using Int64 correctly, or I have a wrong assumption about it's operation.

Any help is appreciated. Code is [here](http://ideone.com/1Okyn).

Comment: Your `getLog` will fail horribly if `n >= 2^62`.

Comment: For what it's worth, `readLineInt` is just [`readLn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:readLn).

Comment: @DanielFischer yes, but n never exceeds 2^31..

Comment: Why are you using `Int64` and not `Word64`?  The latter is an unsigned value so you don't run into the issue with logical shift vs. arithmetic shift.

Comment: @nominolo because the problem might involve negative integers. I have to be very careful to use which when.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stack overflows are a bug in the logic.

```
countOnes !a !b | a == b = countOnes' a

countOnes' :: Int64 -> Integer
countOnes' !0 = 0
countOnes' !a = (fromIntegral (a .&. 1)) + (countOnes' (a `shiftR` 1))
```

Whenever you call `countOnes'` with a negative argument, you get a nonterminating computation, since the `shiftR` is an arithmetic shift and not a logical one, so you always shift in a 1-bit and never reach 0.
But even with a logical shift, for negative arguments, you'd get a result 32 too large, since the top 32 bits are all 1.

Solution: mask out the uninteresting bits before calling `countOnes'`,

```
countOnes !a !b | a == b = countOnes' (a .&. 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

There are some superfluous guards in `countOnes`,

```
countOnes :: Int64 -> Int64 -> Integer
countOnes !a !b | a > b = 0
-- From here on we know a <= b
countOnes !a !b | a == b = countOnes' (a .&. 0xFFFFFFFF)
-- From here on, we know a < b
countOnes !0 !n = range + leading  + (countOnes 0 (n - (1 `shiftL` m)))
    where
        range = fromIntegral $ m * (1 `shiftL` (m - 1))
        leading = fromIntegral $ (n - (1 `shiftL` m) + 1)
        m = (getLog n) - 1
-- From here on, we know a /= 0
countOnes !a !b | a > 0 = (countOnes 0 b) - (countOnes 0 (a - 1))
-- From here on, we know a < 0,
-- the guard in the next and the last equation are superfluous
countOnes !a !0 | a < 0 = countOnes (maxInt + a + 1) maxInt
countOnes !a !b | b < 0 = (countOnes a 0) - (countOnes (b + 1) 0)
countOnes !a !b | a < 0 = (countOnes a 0) + (countOnes 0 b)
```

The integer overflows on the server are caused by

```
getLog :: Int64 -> Int
--
countOnes !0 !n = range + leading  + (countOnes 0 (n - (1 `shiftL` m)))
    where
    range = fromIntegral $ m * (1 `shiftL` (m - 1))
    leading = fromIntegral $ (n - (1 `shiftL` m) + 1)
    m = (getLog n) - 1
```

because the server has a 32-bit GHC, while you have a 64-bit one. The shift distance/bit width `m` is an `Int` (and because it's used as the shift distance, it has to be).

Therefore

```
m * (1 `shiftL` (m-1))
```

is an `Int` too. For `m >= 28`, that overflows a 32-bit `Int`.

Solution: remove a `$`

```
range = fromIntegral m * (1 `shiftL` (m - 1))
```

Then the `1` that is shifted is an `Integer`, hence no overflow.

Comment: actually, `Int` is not 32-bit. It is only guaranteed to be at least 30 bits by the Haskell Report

Comment: Technically, that's possible. But I'm willing to bet that there's a GHC running on the Amazon server, so `Int` is either 32 or 64 bits. I'm not sure about the other implementations, but I expect I'd have heard if any of them actually had `Int`s with other bit lengths.